# SQL update is using old column value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

Given this table

```
create table FOO
(
    ID number(19) primary key,
    DATE1 DATE default sysdate,
    DATE2 DATE
);
```

DATE1 is initialized with sysdate when I insert a row, then set to null and then copied to DATE2:

```
insert into FOO (ID) VALUES (1);
update FOO set DATE1 = null where id = 1;
update FOO set DATE2 = DATE1 where id = 1;
select DATE2 from FOO;
```

DATE2 ends up as null as expected.

But if I create the table in two steps:

```
create table FOO
(
    ID number(19) primary key
);
alter table FOO
    add DATE1 DATE default sysdate
    add DATE2 DATE;
```

and runs the same inserts and updates, DATE2 ends up as the original sysdate value from DATE1. Even though DATE1 ends up as null as expected.

Why this difference? The two tables look the same to me.

Update: describe looks like this in both cases:

```
SQL> describe foo
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                    NOT NULL NUMBER(19)
 DATE1                          DATE
 DATE2                          DATE
```

Comment: Looks like a possible bug to me. There is a difference in the internal structure though, the second method creates a hidden 126 byte raw column you can see in `all_user_cols`. Still doesn't explain the behavior, though.

Comment: FWIW [Postgres doesn't do this](https://dbfiddle.uk/2t_uF0GN), they're usually closer to standard behavior. It exists in Oracle 18, 21, and 23 [but not 11](https://dbfiddle.uk/k58pQdBb). Seems like a bug.

Comment: If you do this first `alter session set "_add_col_optim_enabled"=false;` before creating the table it bypasses the bug. But it will auto-populate the existing rows when you add the new column with default. There are a number of filed bugs around optimized column defaults which have to struggle with how to handle existing rows. Looks like you've found another related bug.

Comment: The bug present in Oracle 18, 21, 23, but not in 11. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/srEjrRR1).

Comment: You should report the bug to [Oracle support](https://support.oracle.com/portal/).

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, this seems to be a bug in some versions of Oracle.

Exhibits expected behavior: Oracle 11.

Exhibits this bug: Oracle 18, 21, 23.

https://dbfiddle.uk/srEjrRR1

Answer (score 0):

I tested it also on Oracle 21C and I think this should be reported to Oracle. But the standard way for you requirement is as follows:

```
1- create table FOO ( ID number(19) primary key);
2- alter table FOO add DATE1 DATE  add DATE2 DATE;
3- alter table foo modify date1 default SYSDATE;
```